# How to keep CSS animation playing while in a hidden DIV

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div containing a button that has some continues animation on it, not just on hover, the whole button is just animated. Then I have a "LOAD MORE" button beneath it, using JavaScript it would load the next div which contains exactly the same button (with animation). Problem is since the 2nd div is display:none till the load more button is clicked, the animation starts at the time the load more button is clicked and therefore becomes inconsistent the the animation of the same button above it. I guess the question is, how do I keep my CSS animation playing in the background of the display:none div so that when its loaded the animation starts at the same time and matches the shown button?

here is a direct link to where the issue is happening, please click LOAD MORE and notice the difference that happens in the CSS animation: [LINK TO ISSUE (LIVE)](https://www.moenagy.dev/assets/links.html)

please see the link above // the first 4 buttons are set to be visible, so the CSS animation on them are consistent. When I click LOAD MORE, the 5th button with was in div with display:none is now visible but starts the CSS animation at different time!! how do I have it load at the same time?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".content").slice(0, 4).show();
  $("#loadMore").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".content:hidden").slice(0, 1).slideDown();
    if ($(".content:hidden").length == 0) {
      $("#loadMore").text("End of Content").addClass("noContent");
    }
  });

})
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}

body {
  width: 100wh;
  height: 90vh;
  color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #F04A30, #F04A30, #303e48, #303e48);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  -webkit-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
  animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes Gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
}

@keyframes Gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
}

.backdrop {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px #111;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px #111;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px #111;
  background-color: #131d27 !important;
}

.linktree {
  background-color: #131d27 !important;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-image: url("https://www.moenagy.dev/assets/images/moeSplash.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.content {
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}

#loadMore {
  width: 200px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #FFF;
  transition: .3s;
}

#loadMore:hover {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid darkslategrey;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.loadButton {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.noContent {
  color: #000 !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  pointer-events: none;
}


/*
 * Animated CSS button
 */

.animated-button1 {
  background: linear-gradient(-30deg, transparent 50%, transparent 50%);
  padding: 20px 40px;
  margin: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2.5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 20px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 80%!important;
}

.animated-button1::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ad8585;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .2s opacity ease-in-out;
  transition: .2s opacity ease-in-out;
}

.animated-button1:hover::before {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

a:hover {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.animated-button1 span {
  position: absolute;
}

.animated-button1 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, from(rgba(43, 8, 8, 0)), to(#d92626));
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(43, 8, 8, 0), #d92626);
  -webkit-animation: 2s animateTop linear infinite;
  animation: 2s animateTop linear infinite;
  visibility: visible;
}

@keyframes animateTop {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.animated-button1 span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 2px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(rgba(43, 8, 8, 0)), to(#d92626));
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(43, 8, 8, 0), #d92626);
  -webkit-animation: 2s animateRight linear -1s infinite;
  animation: 2s animateRight linear -1s infinite;
  visibility: visible;
}

@keyframes animateRight {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}

.animated-button1 span:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(43, 8, 8, 0)), to(#d92626));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(43, 8, 8, 0), #d92626);
  -webkit-animation: 2s animateBottom linear infinite;
  animation: 2s animateBottom linear infinite;
  visibility: visible;
}

@keyframes animateBottom {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.animated-button1 span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 2px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(43, 8, 8, 0)), to(#d92626));
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(43, 8, 8, 0), #d92626);
  -webkit-animation: 2s animateLeft linear -1s infinite;
  animation: 2s animateLeft linear -1s infinite;
  visibility: visible;
}

@keyframes animateLeft {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="text-center" style="padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom: 30px;">
      <img class="backdrop linktree">
      <h2 style="color: #ffffff; padding-top: 20px;">Custom LinkTree :)</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="text-center">

      <div class="content">
        <a href="#" class="animated-button1">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span> LINK # 1
        </a>
      </div>


      <div class="content">
        <a href="#" class="animated-button1">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span> LINK # 2
        </a>
      </div>



      <div class="content">
        <a href="#" class="animated-button1">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span> LINK # 3
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="content">
        <a href="#" class="animated-button1">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span> LINK # 4
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="content">
        <a href="#" class="animated-button1">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span> LINK # 5
        </a>
      </div>


      <div class="content">
        <a href="#" class="animated-button1">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span> LINK # 6
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="loadButton">
    <a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Above is the JS I'm using, so it basically shows the first 4 and then the rest would load. if I use opacity 0 for .content class it will hide them all !!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Rather than having us "picture" something in our minds, why don't you include the relevant code so we can actually test and debug what you're asking? Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: instead of using `display: none` on your div try using `opacity: 0;` or  `width: 0; height: 0;`

Comment: @devsandbox, please see my edit above !!

Comment: @MohamedNagy why not give us the HTML and CSS instead of an image? You can add that to the snippet with your JS.

Comment: @disinfor I added the HTML & CSS

Comment: _" If I use opacity 0 for .content class it will hide them all"_ Create a `.hidden` class which applies `opacity:0` or `width: 0; height: 0;` and add it to the elements that should be hidden initially. Then remove that class from the next element every time the "load more" button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've re-implemented using a class, so now the elements are on the page all the time, but only show on click. I've left as much of the original code as I could.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".content").slice(0, 4).addClass('show');
  $("#loadMore").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".content:not(.show)").slice(0, 1).addClass('show').slideDown();
    if ($(".content.show").length == 0) {
      $("#loadMore").text("End of Content").addClass("noContent");
    }
  });

})
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}

body {
  width: 100wh;
  height: 90vh;
  color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #F04A30, #F04A30, #303e48, #303e48);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  -webkit-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
  animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes Gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
}

@keyframes Gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
}

.backdrop {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px #111;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px #111;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px #111;
  background-color: #131d27 !important;
}

.linktree {
  background-color: #131d27 !important;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-image: url("https://www.moenagy.dev/assets/images/moeSplash.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.content {
  padding: 10px;

  width:0px;
  height:0px;
}

.content a {
  padding: 0;
}

.show {
  width:unset;
  height:unset;
}

.content.show a {
  padding: 20px 40px;
}


#loadMore {
  width: 200px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #FFF;
  transition: .3s;
}

#loadMore:hover {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid darkslategrey;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.loadButton {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.noContent {
  color: #000 !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  pointer-events: none;
}


/*
 * Animated CSS button
 */

.animated-button1 {
  background: linear-gradient(-30deg, transparent 50%, transparent 50%);
  padding: 20px 40px;
  margin: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2.5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 20px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 80%!important;
}

.animated-button1::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ad8585;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .2s opacity ease-in-out;
  transition: .2s opacity ease-in-out;
}

.animated-button1:hover::before {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

a:hover {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.animated-button1 span {
  position: absolute;
}

.animated-button1 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, from(rgba(43, 8, 8, 0)), to(#d92626));
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(43, 8, 8, 0), #d92626);
  -webkit-animation: 2s animateTop linear infinite;
  animation: 2s animateTop linear infinite;
  visibility: visible;
}

@keyframes animateTop {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.animated-button1 span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 2px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(rgba(43, 8, 8, 0)), to(#d92626));
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(43, 8, 8, 0), #d92626);
  -webkit-animation: 2s animateRight linear -1s infinite;
  animation: 2s animateRight linear -1s infinite;
  visibility: visible;
}

@keyframes animateRight {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}

.animated-button1 span:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(43, 8, 8, 0)), to(#d92626));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(43, 8, 8, 0), #d92626);
  -webkit-animation: 2s animateBottom linear infinite;
  animation: 2s animateBottom linear infinite;
  visibility: visible;
}

@keyframes animateBottom {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.animated-button1 span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 2px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(43, 8, 8, 0)), to(#d92626));
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(43, 8, 8, 0), #d92626);
  -webkit-animation: 2s animateLeft linear -1s infinite;
  animation: 2s animateLeft linear -1s infinite;
  visibility: visible;
}

@keyframes animateLeft {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="text-center" style="padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom: 30px;">
      <img class="backdrop linktree">
      <h2 style="color: #ffffff; padding-top: 20px;">Custom LinkTree :)</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="text-center">

      <div class="content">
        <a href="#" class="animated-button1">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span> LINK # 1
        </a>
      </div>


      <div class="content">
        <a href="#" class="animated-button1">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span> LINK # 2
        </a>
      </div>



      <div class="content">
        <a href="#" class="animated-button1">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span> LINK # 3
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="content">
        <a href="#" class="animated-button1">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span> LINK # 4
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="content">
        <a href="#" class="animated-button1">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span> LINK # 5
        </a>
      </div>


      <div class="content">
        <a href="#" class="animated-button1">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span> LINK # 6
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="loadButton">
    <a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked great // made a few edits to it but it does work as needed. Thanx again!